# The bitwise operators should not be used in place of logical operators

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, ternary-operator

```
//  How does this program work with ternary operator
#include <stdio.h>   
int main()
{
    int x = 2, y = 5;
    (x &  y) ? printf("True ") : printf("False "); // How do we get output
    (x && y) ? printf("True ") : printf("False ");
    return 0;
}
```

How does this program work?
How do the logical and bitwise operators work?

Comment: output:False and True

Comment: Related,  [Conditional Statement using Bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10034470/608639) and [How does condition statement work with bit-wise operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13054401/608639)

Comment: @manjunathhiremath is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 3):

In this program `&` is a bitwise operator which will do bitwise `and` operation on 2 and 5.

```
0000 0010<=2
0000 0101<=5
0000 0000<=output
```

So the first line will print `False`,
whereas second one is normal `and` operator for which both values are true(non zero numbers ) so `2 && 5` will result in true and the output will be `True`.

Answer (score 0):

*The bitwise AND operator is a single ampersand: &. A handy mnemonic is that the small version of the boolean AND, &&, works on smaller pieces (bits instead of bytes, chars, integers, etc). In essence, a binary AND simply takes the logical AND of the bits in each position of a number in binary form.*

Example for & (**and**):

```
00000010 & //2
00000101 = //5
--------
00000000   // 0
```

*Bitwise OR works almost exactly the same way as bitwise AND. The only difference is that only one of the two bits needs to be a 1 for that position's bit in the result to be 1. (If both bits are a 1, the result will also have a 1 in that position.) The symbol is a pipe: |. Again, this is similar to boolean logical operator, which is ||.*

Example for | (**OR**):

```
00000010 | //2
00000101 = //5
--------
00000111 //7
```

*There is no boolean operator counterpart to bitwise exclusive-or, but there is a simple explanation. The exclusive-or operation takes two inputs and returns a 1 if either one or the other of the inputs is a 1, but not if both are. That is, if both inputs are 1 or both inputs are 0, it returns 0. Bitwise exclusive-or, with the operator of a caret, ^, performs the exclusive-or operation on each pair of bits. Exclusive-or is commonly abbreviated XOR.*

Example for ^ (**XOR**):

```
00000010 ^ //2
00000101 = //5
--------
00000111 //7
```

If you get into a bitwise operators I suggest you get a pen and paper, imagine 2 random 8 bit numbers and work them all up on paper(all bitwise operations). Then you can find a Programmer calculator and check out your result.

Comment: No problem , if you need more help do not hesitate to ask.I will be more than happy to assist you. Also if you found my answer helpfull I would much apreciate if you upvote/accept my answer. Thanks.